Isomorphism $\mathbb Z[\omega]/(1-\omega)^2\cong (\mathbb Z/(p))[x]/(1-X)^2$, $\omega$ is the $p-$th root of unity.
Im reading the following proof of Fermat's Last Theorem from Keith Conrad
https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/fltreg.pdf
On page 5 he mentions that $\mathbb Z[\omega]/(1-\omega)^2\cong (\mathbb Z/(p))[x]/(1-X)^2$, where $\omega$ is a $p-$th root of unity. I've been trying to figure out how is this isomorphism established but I couldn't do it.

It's a good practice to write $\Bbb Z/(p)$ instead of $\Bbb Z_p$ because $\Bbb Z_p$ is usually denoted as $p-$adic integers. Or you can define what you want to mean in the question. This is just a suggestion.

Is $\omega$ a $p$-th root of unity?

@cansomeonehelpmeout Yes

We have the isomorphism $$\Bbb Z[x]/(\Phi_p(x))=\Bbb Z[\omega]\tag{1}$$ given by $x\mapsto \omega$. If $f(\omega)=0$, then $\Phi_p(x)\mid f(x)$ by definition, so $\ker(x\mapsto\omega)\subseteq (\Phi_p(x))$. $(\Phi_p(x))\subseteq \ker(x\mapsto\omega)$ is also clear. Also,
$$\Phi_p(x)=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}\equiv_p\frac{(x-1)^p}{(x-1)}\equiv_p(x-1)^{p-1}\tag{2}$$ And so, we also have the isomorphism $$\Bbb Z_p[x]/(x-1)^{p-1}\cong\Bbb Z_p[\omega]\tag{3}$$
Notice also that $p=u(1-\omega)^{p-1}$ for a unit $u\in\Bbb Z[\omega]$. Combining these we get:
$$\begin{align}\Bbb Z[\omega]/(1-\omega)^2&\cong\Bbb Z[\omega]/(p, (1-\omega)^2))\\&\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(p,\Phi_p(x),(x-1)^2)\\&\cong\Bbb Z_p[x]/((x-1)^{p-1},(x-1)^2)\\&\cong\Bbb Z_p[x]/(x-1)^2\end{align}$$

Another way to state it:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}0 @>>>(x-1)^2@>{i_1}>>\Bbb Z_p[x]/(x-1)^{p-1} @>{\pi_1}>> \Bbb Z_p[x]/(x-1)^2@>>>0
\\
~ @V{u_1}VV @V{u_2}VV @V{u_3}VV
\\
0 @>>>(1-\omega)^2@>{i_2}>>\Bbb Z[\omega] @>{\pi_2}>> \Bbb Z[\omega]/(1-\omega)^2@>>>0
\end{CD}
The rows are exact, and $u_1,u_2,u_3$ defined by $x\mapsto \omega$ are isomorphisms.
